# Why is my for loop breaking earlier than expected?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, break

I am trying to solve a problem on leetCode:

Given an unsorted integer array nums, return the smallest missing positive integer.
This is the code I came up with

```
var firstMissingPositive = function(nums) {
    nums.sort();
    let x = 1;  //this is to compare the elements of nums
    for (let num in nums) {
      if (nums[num] <= 0) continue; //because anything less than 1 does not matter
      else if (nums[num] != x) break; //if x is not present, x is the answer
      else x++;                      // if x is present, x should increment and check for the next integer
    }
    return x;
};
```

This code works 106/173 testcases. It does not pass the following case, which looks very simple -

```
nums = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,20];
```

The output I get is 3, whereas the expected output is 10.

I'm not looking for the right solution to the problem. I'm just curious why this seemingly simple test fails. I do not understand why my loop breaks at 3 when it passes 1 and 2. Please help!

Comment: console.log() is your friend. `for (let num in nums) { console.log(num, nums[num], nums[num] <= 0, nums[num] != x);`

Comment: `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 20].sort() = [1, 2, 20, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the root cause of your problem ([mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)):

> The sort() method sorts the elements of an array in place and returns
> the sorted array. The default sort order is ascending, built upon
> **converting the elements into strings**, then comparing their sequences
> of UTF-16 code units values.

So what you get after sort is `[1, 2, 20, 3, ...]`, as '20' string precedes '3' string. One possible way to fix this it to [force sorting by numeric value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1063007/how-to-sort-an-array-of-integers-correctly):

```
nums.sort((a, b) => a - b);
```